# Laravel Before Filter

Tags: laravel

Can some guide me this line I already read at forum also some blog but not clearing the logic

```
 array('before' => 'auth', 'do' => function()
```

Comment: Before executing the code behind the route auth/ do something.

Comment: if current state is "Before Authentication" do the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply suppose that you want to check if the user is logged in or not before doing certain action, its done by something called filters.
'before' filter means execute the filter before execute the action.

for more inofrmation about filters check [this link](http://laravel.com/docs/routing#filters)

example:

```
Route::get('home', array('before' => 'auth', 'do' => function()
{
    // your action here
}));


Route::filter('auth',function(){
     if(Auth::guest())
         return Redirect::to('login');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

This [link](http://codehappy.daylerees.com/authentication) explains the same. The plain meaning is *if current state is "Before Authentication" do the function* .

When you try to post, if you are not logged in, this will redirect you to `function()` which performs login purposes. Here `auth` is the event and `function` is event handler

Comment: Route::post('admin', array('before' => 'auth', 'do' => function() {
    // handle the create new post form
})); I am confused why before authentication to post the form ? Because authentication need to be perform for authentic logic, If before first its mean before authentication post the data. so when authentication will perform ?

Comment: some pages have textboxes to post data like SO. and when you enter text and try to post it redirect you yo login

Answer (score 0):

This means that the auth filter has to be executed before doing the action in the "do callback". If the filter returns a response(like in [the CodeHappy example](http://codehappy.daylerees.com/authentication)) the do callback will not be executed.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take this step by step,

```
array('before' => 'auth', 'do' => function()
```

parameters to array,

***before***

This refers to filters. Filters are functions which are executed before a request is processed.

In your case above the ***do*** part of array parameters refers to the function that will be executed in the current request. But before that function can execute ***auth*** filter is run.

You can also specify multiple filters to execute with the ***before*** parameter.

```
for example: 'before' => array('csrf', 'auth', 'mycustomfilter')
```

Answer (score 0):

The "auth" filter is used to authenticate the users in application before access the function.

let's consider, you have following code in routes.php

```
  Route::get('index', array('before' => 'auth', 'do' => function()
  {
       // application logic goes here
  }));
```

hence, you have to specific auth filter in filters.php file as below

1) return the json response

```
   Route::filter('auth', function()
   {
      if (!Auth::check()) {
        return Response::json(array('flash' => 'Please log in.'), 401);
      }
   });
```

or

2) redirect to login view

```
    Route::filter('auth', function()
    {
       if (!Auth::check()) {
         return Redirect::to('login');
       }
    });
```